# How to set the SwitchPreference style to a "normal" switch?

Tags: android

#### Updated question

I have the following `layout` for an `AppCompatActivity`:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/swcExample"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="example" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

...which is just a normal `Switch` component, when I activate it it looks like this:

[image: The standard switch ripple effect]

But I want the `Switch` to behave like this:

[image: The full-component ripple effect]

(I tricked it with a `FrameLayout`)

---

The question is, how could I get the 2nd ripple effect with a normal `Switch` (see code above).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is "the... ripple effect" that is separate from "the animation"? What is "it" in "how to customize it"? `RippleDrawable` is the stock solution for implementing a ripple, but it is unclear whether that is what you are looking for.

Comment: @CommonsWare I updated the question with code and images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` property to your Switch.

Comment: I have been using `background` instead of `foreground`, that is exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

That ripple effect is usually seen on Android 5.0+.

If you want the ripple to simply appear on the row, and your `minSdkVersion` is 21 or higher, add the following attributes to your `LinearLayout`:

```
  android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
  android:clickable="true"
  android:focusable="true"
```

That will not toggle the switch, though, when the row is clicked. You would need to add a `View.OnClickListener` to the `LinearLayout` and toggle the switch as appropriate.

If your `minSdkVersion` is below 21, and you want the platform-standard selection event to occur (ripple on 5.0+, row flash on 4.4 and older), what I show above should work. If you want the ripple on older devices... there may be a recipe for that, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: I have used that solution for layouts, but the @ayush-maharjan 's answer achieves exactly what I was looking for, thank you for sharing anyway.